# virtualbox keeps showing error "Kernel driver not installed"

Tags: virtualbox, dkms

I'm trying to install a `Windows7` guest on a `Linux` host with Virtual box. I've set my guest up but when I hit `start`, I keep getting the message:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
```

I've ran`/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` n the shell but nothing happens and the error keeps popping up, how can I get this resolved?
Oh yeah, and I've installed `dkms` already:
`# apt-get install dkms`

**EDIT 1**

```
# modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.
```

**EDIT 2**

There's `virtualbox-guest-dkms` and `virtualbox-dkms` and I have them both installed but I still get the same error...

Comment: It seems like this is a fairly common issue. Try the steps outlined at [these](http://askubuntu.com/questions/442951/virtual-box-not-running-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue) [sites](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2179980). [Also](http://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue)

Comment: Does you distro provide prebuilt packages for the VirtualBox modules (if so, use those)? What happens if you `modprobe vboxdrv` manually?

Comment: @Renan Mydistribution is **Kubuntu 14.04**. Please see above **EDIT 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use `sudo`. Run it like this and it will work:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo su
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

see if it works now.

I am trying to use it too. I had the same problem.
I did the following in the terminal:

```
sudo su
```

I don't have a virtual machine yet, but this problem/error is solved for me after doing this.

Comment: Generally when people represent the shell prompt with `#` instead of `$`, it means they're running as root

Comment: On RedHat/Fedora, it's `yum install dkms`. `kernel-devel` might also be required.

Comment: What would one do if running `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` returns `bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory`?

Answer (score 2):

Took me a long time to solve this issue. Had this problem with vBox across 2 distros (Ubuntu and Arch).

I had dkms and all the modules already installed and compiled into my kernel, yet I still got a module related error message when I tried to run a vBox virtual machine.

If your vBox GUI starts without a hitch but get an error telling you to install the VBoxDrv kernel module (or any other modules) when you try to run a virtual machine, your problems are not related to installing the modules into your kernel but *activating them* in modprobe which the module installation script fails to do.

To load a module manually (such as `vboxdrv`), open a terminal prompt and put in:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

if your error message is telling you that your missing another module, be sure to activate it as well.

If you Virtual Machine runs after that without giving you an error message, you've found the solution. Then you can activate the vboxdrv module permanently by going to `/etc/modules-load.d/` (or whatever `.d` directory your modprobe uses) and making a .conf file within it (such as `vbox.conf`). In the .conf file, put in the names of the vbox kernel modules you want to add, such as: `vboxdrv` and optionally `vboxnetadp`, `vboxnetflt` and `vboxpci`. If you don't know what they do, see the excerpt below that I took out of vBox's wiki. Save the .conf file and reboot

From Vbox's wiki:

`vboxnetadp` and `vboxnetflt` are both needed when you intend to use the "Host-only networking" feature. More precisely, `vboxnetadp` is needed to create the host interface in the VirtualBox global preferences, and `vboxnetflt` is needed to launch a virtual machine using that network interface.

`vboxpci` is needed when your virtual machine needs to pass through a PCI device on your host.

Note: If the VirtualBox kernel modules were loaded in the kernel while you updated the modules, you need to reload them manually to use the new updated version. To do it, run `vboxreload` as root.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the VirtualBox kernel modules.  I believe the package you need is `virtualbox-ose-dkms`.

Answer (score 1):

I was banging my head with this one too.

I was using the virtualbox.repo with CentOS 7

Here is what I came up with:

```
# yum remove VirtualBox-5.0
# yum -y update kernel kernel-firmware
# yum -y install kernel-devel
# yum -y install epel-release
# yum -y install dkms
# yum -y install VirtualBox-5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First:  Uninstall virtualbox-dkms and its configurations by running the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
```

Second:  Install Linux headers and Linux image by running the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64
```

Last: Install virtualbox-dkms

```
sudo apt-get install -y virtualbox-dkms
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps it solved for me
1.Boot your device and then **disable** the secure boot
2.Then run `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` in your terminal
  I think this will solve your problem